# Windows 7 64 bit on MacPro

Tags: windows-7, mac, 64-bit

My MacPro would not read the 64 bit version of Windows 7 but loaded the 32 bit version without hardly any problem.

Is the disk likely to be faulty or is there a problem with 64 bit on some Macs?

Answer (score 1):

I've installed Win7 64bit on my Mac Pro without any problem.
I'd say you have a problem with your installation DVD

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if the CD is faulty. I am most certain that all Mac Pros are now 64-bit compatible (in fact, Snow Leopard is 64 bit).

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to a larger hard disk recently and had to recreate my bootcamp partition. When it came time to install Windows stuff, *none* of the CDs/DVDs worked. The problem turned out to be my two-year-old SuperDrive -- apparently there have been larger than average numbers of failures in Apple laptop optical drives. Since I was still under AppleCare, I had the optical drive replaced and voila -- no more problems.